# Show sticky post before other WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, order, sticky-post

```
$recent_posts = new WP_Query(
   array('posts_per_page'       => $blog_num_posts,
         'paged'                => $paged,
         'post_type'            => 'post',
         'post_status'          => 'publish',
         'cat'                  => $categories,
         'category__not_in'     => $categories_exclude,
         'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 0
    ));
```

This should load all recent_posts including the sticky posts - now I want to order them according to the "stickyness" but i can't figure out how..

WP Version (Version 4.0)

Comment: Does it not happen? Where _does_ sticky posts end up in order?

Comment: Just one question, why are you using `cat` and `category__not_in` together. If you use the `cat` parameter, all other categories not explicitly added to the `cat` parameter will be excluded by default

Comment: It's a snap out of the template i used for this. the porblem is that the sticky posts will show up but not ordered as the first once.

Comment: Do you want the sticky posts in the beginning of the result set?

Comment: They end up ordered by date like the other posts..

Comment: @Krister Andersson that's right

Comment: @Pieter Goosen i also don't know why this will be used at this point but as mentioned It's a snap out of the template i'm using i only want to change some ordering of the sticky and at the moment i don't have the time to think about the "logic" behind another developer was thinking.